# How to do lower() and raise() for QGraphicsItem in Qt?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I wanted to changed z-order of graphicsitems in my graphicsscene.
I have used QGraphicsWebView as graphicsitem.
How can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use setZValue, isObscured and isObscuredBy. Documentation is precise about these methods.

Comment: This is interesting to read as well: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgraphicsitem.html#sorting.